# Is it possible to Save the DWM_THUMBNAIL Image?

Tags: c#

I try to make an program that takes the THUMBNAIL image and then take an screen shot of the project. When i open the project image the THUMBNAIL image is not there. But when i press the Print Screen button at the keyboard the image is fine.

Can someone help me?

[image: keyboard Screen Shot]

Comment: Could you please show the code that takes the thumbnail image, so we can take a look and help find the problem.  Without seeing your code, it would be very difficult to make useful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void UpdateThumb()
    {
        if (thumb != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            PSIZE size;
            DwmQueryThumbnailSourceSize(thumb, out size);

            DWM_THUMBNAIL_PROPERTIES props = new DWM_THUMBNAIL_PROPERTIES();

            props.fVisible = true;
            props.dwFlags = DWM_TNP_VISIBLE | DWM_TNP_RECTDESTINATION | DWM_TNP_OPACITY;
            props.opacity = (byte)opacity.Value;
            props.rcDestination = new Rect(image.Left, image.Top, image.Right, image.Bottom);

            if (size.x < image.Width)
                props.rcDestination.Right = props.rcDestination.Left + size.x;

            if (size.y < image.Height)
                props.rcDestination.Bottom = props.rcDestination.Top + size.y;


            DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties(thumb, ref props);
        }
    }
```